# Conditional styling of an element in visual structure

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have trouble making a universal solution for next problem:

Imagine a custom TreeView control that a;;pws theming - there is a list of elements in separate xaml file that is used to build a visual structure for TreeView control. There is onm Border element that I would like to paint its background based on type of data that is dsiplayed. This border element is part of "+" sign, and is not exposed through a style.

I can do this using code behind, and subscribing to some of the events that this control provides, then find this border in child elements, and change its background. However, this code will be repeated in many views, sometimes exactly the same, sometimes with slightly different modifications (ex only a different data element is checked for type).

Is there a way I can do this using any other technique? It seems that style selectors can be used here, since visual structure is not built at that poinr, so I cannot search this element by its name. And this element is not exposed through any property on the control.

Edit:

currently I am having my oqwn control that inherit this control, if you find thazt it can be done using Attached/depenency propertyies:

```
public class MyTreeView : CustomTreeView
{
}
```

If I ere to poaint a background for a row I would create a style selector:

```
<local:ProductRowtyleSelector x:Key="productRowStyleSelector"
                              DefaultStyle="{StaticResource defaultProductRowStyle}"
                              GoodStyle="{StaticResource goodProductRowStyle}"
                              ScrapStyle="{StaticResource reworkProductRowStyle}" />
```

Where GoodStyle would inherit the style for a row that exists in control template. This way I would use style selecor anywhere I displayt list of Products.

Is there a similar way that I would do the same for the Border element that I added in control template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Ok if I get what you need, you can try this

Create a IsTypeOf IValueConverter like this :

```
public class IsTypeOfConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type parameterType = parameter as Type;
        if (parameterType == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml, put a DataTrigger in the applicable style

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsKindOfConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type Person}}">
    <Setter Property="Backgroud" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi Sisyphe, I do not want to do it on different controls, I already inherit custom treeview and I would like to do it from there, if possible. Also, this logic needs to be applied on the row level, that is part of items collection.

Comment: Ok sorry I totally missed the point. So you want to browse the visual tree looking for a specific item to do some work on ?

Comment: Hi Sisyphe, What I did is added one Border element (x:Name="MyBorder") into the theme (theme is the xaml file where visual structure is created for this list control. Imagine that this list control is bound to List<Customer>. In code behind, whenerver a row is loaded on this list control, I find a child element by name "MyBorder", and set its background, based on the Type property of the Customer. And now imagine that I copy paste this code on each view where I have List<Customer>. Also, I have List<Product>, and Product also has a Type property.. you get the pirture.

Comment: What I was thinking is to find a way to make some converter, or styleselector, or templateselecor, where I could reuse this on each view. Problem with StyleSelector is that when it is fired visual structure is not yet build. So in this question I ask for any idea how to make this reusable (without creating static class and moving the code from code behind there).

Comment: So you want to set a different background color for rows in a Listbox, depending on the DataContext object type right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18305/discussion-between-sisyphe-and-goran)